# Connect-mongodb-session: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Store' of undefined (mongodb, nodejs, connect-mongodb-session)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-modules

After I've upgraded the connect-mongo npm, app keeps crashing due to this error: Could you please, to fix this error?

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"connect-mongodb-session": "^2.2.0",
"express": "^4.16.4",
"express-handlebars": "^3.0.2",
"express-session": "^1.16.1",
"mongoose": "^5.5.3",
"uuid": "^3.3.2"
}
```

app.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongodb-session');

const store = new MongoStore({
  collections: 'sessions',
  uri: MONGODB_URI
})
```

I've tried to change "connect-mongodb-session" versions, didn't help. Can anyone advise a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialize store with **session**

```
var MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
```

Comment: I need to change:  const MongoStore = require('connect-mongodb-session') to var 
MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session); ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

Have tried to initialize store with session:

```
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const store = new MongoDBStore({
 uri: MONGODB_URI,
 collections: 'sessions'
});

store.on('error', function(error) {
   console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a really dumb mistake.

```
var MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')('session');
```

I had session in qoutes!

```
var MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session); //No quotes around session
```